# Alterar a qualidade de um Stream de vídeo c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, streaming

Estou precisando alterar a qualidade de um vídeo que esta sendo stremado pela minha Api, eu já estou enviando o arquivo, agora estou precisando alterar a qualidade dele na hora da transmissão, segue o meu código abaixo:

```
               var buffer = new byte[65536];

                using (var video = File.Open(_filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    var length = (int)video.Length;
                    var bytesRead = 1;

                    while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        bytesRead = video.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));
                        await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        length -= bytesRead;
                    }
                }
```

Existe alguma forma de alterar na hora do streaming ou eu preciso ter ele fisicamente nas outras qualidades?

Comment: Normalmente, a qualidade do vídeo não é definida pela forma pela qual você alimenta o *buffer*, e sim pela taxa de amostragem do vídeo. Significa que você tem que trabalhar esse *buffer* de alguma forma antes.

Comment: Entendi, irei ver aqui uma forma e depois posto a forma, vlw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o Cigano Morrison comentou. A qualidade do vídeo não definida na hora de transmitir o stream, mas sim no encode do video.

Se você está usando arquivos físicos precisará ter "copias" deles encodados com as características que você espera. Pode até automatizar o processo usando a [biblioteca do FFmpeg](https://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/)

Para transmissões ao vivo você pode configurar em seu enconder os profiles, diversos endpoints para as variações de qualidade ou entregar o conteúdo em tracks apresentados em um manifesto para Adaptative bitrate Streaming ou Smooth Stream.